# How do I organize lower and upper case words in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, case, words

Here is the code I have.

All I need to do is make sure the list is organized with upper case words first and lower case words second. I looked around but no luck with `.sort` or `.sorted` command.

```
string = input("Please type in a string? ")

words = string.strip().split()
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Comment: What do you mean by organise? sort?

Comment: This should already be happening by default using `words.sort()` or `words = sorted(words)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = raw_input("Please type in a string? ")
words = string.strip().split()
words.sort()
```

As to how to separate upper and lower case words into separate columns:

```
string = raw_input("Please type in a string? ")
words = string.split()
column1 = []
column2 = []
for word in words:
    if word.islower():
        column1.append(word)
    else
        column2.append(word)
```

The `.islower()` function evaluates to true if all the letters are lower case. If this doesn't work for your problem's definition of upper and lower case, look into the .isupper() and .istitle() methods [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: `.strip()` is unnecessary in this case; all spaces are ignored with `.split()` anyway.

Comment: Hey Justin, is there anything else I can use instead of .sort() to get the words organized in a column?

Answer (score 1):

The `sorted()` function should sort items alphabetically taking caps into account.

```
>>> string = "Don't touch that, Zaphod Beeblebox!"
>>> words = string.split()
>>> print( sorted(words) )
['Beeblebox!', "Don't", 'Zaphod', 'that,', 'touch']
```

But if for some reason `sorted()` ignored caps, then you could do it manually with a sort of list comprehension if you wanted:

```
words = sorted([i for i in words if i[0].isupper()]) + sorted([i for i in words if i[0].islower()])
```

This creates two separate lists, the first with capitalized words and the second without, then sorts both individually and conjoins them to give the same result.

But in the end you should definitely just use `sorted()`; it's much more efficient and concise.

---

**EDIT:** Sorry, I might have miss-interpreted your question; if you want to organize just *Caps* and *not* without sorting alphabetically, then this works:

```
>>> string = "ONE TWO one THREE two three FOUR"
>>> words = string.split()
>>> l = []
>>> print [i for i in [i if i[0].isupper() else l.append(i) for i in words] if i!=None]+l
['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

I can't find a method that's more efficient then that, so there you go.

Comment: `sorted()` doesn't ignore caps, it's just the way how python compares strings. `ord('Z') == 90`, and `ord('a') == 97`. This is how python compares/sorts letters. As 90 is less than 97, it is placed before

Comment: What the exercise is looking for is for the program to organize the words in the following manner:Input your text: Python and Perl are both programming languages
Python
Perl
and
are
both
programming
languages